# Difference between AdMob and DFP networks?

Tags: ios, admob, ads, google-dfp

I am trying to display banner as well as Interstitial ads on my iOS application. But now I am confused on ad networks. How the AdMob is different from DFP and which one is better to serve ads. Can anybody give some help ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

AdMob is an ad network. You as a publisher can earn money by displaying ads delivered from the network. You'll be paid from AdMob without any direct contact to the advertising companies.

DfP is an ad server offered as a cloud solution. You can set up an instance yourself but it's empty. It contains no ads. You'll need to go out, acquire ad campaigns from advertisers, book the campaign into the ad server and display the ads in your app. You'll be in direct contact with the advertising companies and get the money directly from them.

For simple monetization, go with AdMob. If you have a very popular app and depending on the market you're in, you might want to set up a sales team that acquires premium ad campaigns. Then you can use DfP for managing your premium campaigns and even configure it to use AdMob for ad impressions not filled by your premium campaigns.

Comment: Can you use DFP like AdMob mediation? That is to mediate multiple ad networks (with integrated SDKs), without doing any direct deal.

Comment: @Sébastien: I'm no longer working with DFP so I can't tell you the current state. A few years ago, DFP itself couldn't do it. We implemented it by delivering Javascript from an ad network code from DFP, which executes in the user's browser or mobile phone, connects to the ad network and selects some ad. It's a poor solution. DFP thinks that an ad has successfully been delivered and opens the ad area even if the ad network cannot deliver an ad.