# Difference between AdmobBanner & PublisherBanner in React Native Admob for Google Admob?

Tags: react-native, admob

I don't know if [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24704319/6141587) is the same answer for my question.

Basically, what I want to know is the difference between [AdmobBanner](https://github.com/sbugert/react-native-admob/blob/master/RNAdMobBanner.js) & [PublisherBanner](https://github.com/sbugert/react-native-admob/blob/master/RNPublisherBanner.js) in [react-native-admob](https://github.com/sbugert/react-native-admob/)?

They basically look the same & have similar properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**AdMobBanner** is the `react-native-admob`-way to show an advertisement delivered by the AdMob Network. You just have to register there and pass in your `adUnitID` and they will handle all the stuff for you.

**PublisherBanner** has the same properties as AdMobBanner, with the addition of two new properties (`onAppEvent` and `validAdSizes`). It is used to show ads provided by DfP.

Comment: Why would a developer pick one over the other?

Comment: @CarlG For most of the developers the `AdMobBanner` is the best choice. Here you don't have to sell ads by your own. Google will do all the stuff for you. Only if you are creating an app for a big company and you/they want to publish/sell your/their own ads, then the `PublishBanner` might be an option for you.

Comment: Thank you for that clarification.